# trying to print a name when the ID Number is the same as what i have entered into text field

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, object

what i would like to know is how would i display the name of a customer (it is an object instance of the object Customer) using the ID number attached to it. this is what i have tried so far and it is not working:

```
int number = [nunmber intValue];
Customer *customer = [list objectAtIndex:(memberNumber == number)];
NSLog(@"member:%@",customer.name);
NSLog(@"number:%i",number);
```

all this does is it prints the name of the first person in the table
thanks for any help.
i am programming in xcode 4 for osx

Comment: It doesn't work because you've passed a Boolean expression to `-objectAtIndex:` that equates to either 0 or 1, not the number of the `Customer` whose `name` you want. Where does `memberNumber` come from? Is that the ID number ivar of the object? Your question's not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate (fast enumeration) over the list:

```
for (Customer *c in list) {
  if ([c memberNumber]==nunmber) {
    NSLog(@"member %@ with number %@ found",[c name],[c memberNumber]);
  }  
}
```

Provided that `nunmber` and `memberNumber` are of same type.
Your approach with `...:(memberNumber==number)` will either give you the first element (if memberNumber!=number) with index 0 or the second element (if memberNumber==number), since you effectively perform a test and consequently get a boolean with either 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks for accepting :) One more thing: You should break from the for-loop if you have found your match, else you would inefficiently iterate always the whole array. Personally i would use `NSPredicate` searching as shown below (it depends a bit on the size of the array and purpose of the search)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Customer *customer = [list objectAtIndex:number];
```

**Edit**

You can use an instance of `NSPredicate` to filter the array based on the member number as follows:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"memberNumber == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:memberNumber]];
NSArray *matchingMembers = [members filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

Customer *customer = [matchingMembers lastObject];
NSLog(@"%@", customer.name);
```

Comment: this sort of works. what i am trying to do is get the name of a customer who's memberNumber is equal to the number